# PFC formula for calculating conduction losses across MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switch-mode-power-supply, power-factor-correction

I am not able to demonstrate the formula above where Vin is the input voltage of the PFC, Vout is the output voltage, Po is the output power, and Rds(on) is the on resistance of the mosfet. This formula is given into the following datasheet and is used in a 2-interleaved PFC. That's why I think there is a 0.5 factor, if we supposed that the loss are equally distrubued on the 2 Mosfets. https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua479b/slua479b.pdf?ts=1615697963421

[image]

The problem comes from the fact that the rms current of the mosfet depends on the current seen by the inductance during on time and this current follows a sinusoidal on a half period line (100/120 Hz). That's why I think we observe a "Pi". The PFC is working in CCM.

[image]

Is there someone who could help me to demonstrate this formula ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day.

Comment: What is the question in your question?

Comment: Edited :) Thank you !

Comment: What page is it on?

Comment: Calculating average losses in a PFC stage is a complicated exercise. This is because you have to determine the instantaneous power \$p(t)\$ across a switching cycle and then integrate along the mains cycle to obtain the average power. A similar approach applies if you want to determine rms currents for instance. The process is described in my green book on power supplies but this application note [AND8123](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8123-D.PDF) from M. Turchi is an excellent source to follow the steps.

Comment: Thank you for your replies ! I will take a look on the A.N. I hope I could follow the same method for a converter working in CCM. I think i have a book which is green at my office, I will open it to see if I could find this information on it !